# Should I dual boot or get rid of Windows and just run Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot

For the last 3 years my laptop has been dual boot Ubuntu and Windows Vista. I hardly ever go into Windows at all. I am going to replace my laptop next month with a Dell XPS 13. The SSD is only 128GB which isn't a huge amount of space, especially if partitioning for dual boot. Is there any reason I should keep Windows at all, or should I just get rid of it and have it dedicated to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need Windows for anything, like Netflix streaming, iTunes, etc, you can either keep it, but with a small partition, or better yet - assuming you have a bootable Windows CD, use VirtualBox to create a Windows VM so you don't even need to leave Ubuntu to run the windows programs.  I use this method, and it works well, although I use it with XP, which is probably less resource intensive.

If you're keeping your old laptop, you could just use that for your emergency Windows usage.

Comment: A virtual drive is specially useful if you have low space on your Hard Drive, since it "grows". +1